# Series representations for non-analytic smooth functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

Given a complex valued polynomial $$P(z) = \sum_{n=0}^N c_n z^n, \ \ c_n \in \mathbb{C}$$

I'm trying to find some non-trivial series representation in terms of $z$ for $$f(z) = \frac{P^2(z)}{|P(z)|^2}.$$

However I'm at a loss for how to do this.  It's not holomorphic, as it depends implicitly on the conjugate of $z$, so I don't think you can construct a power series or Laurent series, for instance, which would be the obvious thing to try.

Are there any other techniques that would work here?  Maybe something like a Laurent series that works on arbitrary smooth functions?

Comment: You have to have $\bar z$ terms; the function is real analytic outside zeroes of polynomial so it has series in $x,y$

Comment: @Conrad Yeah I'm not sure how to do it but if there was a way to express it as a linear combination of powers of $z$ and $\overline{z}$ and maybe $|z|$ that would be just fine.

Comment: For example if $P(0) \ne 0$ you can express it as $P(z)S(\bar z)$ where $S$ is a Taylor series in $\bar z$ convergent up to the modulus of lowest root of the polynomial